# Does crafting ammunition create one piece, or a batch?

Tags: crafting, pathfinder-2e

I'm looking at the rules for crafting, and I'm somewhat surprised to see the following:

> You must spend 4 days at work, at which point you attempt a Crafting check. The GM determines the DC to Craft the item based on its level, rarity, and other circumstances.

So if a wizard were to craft a staff, it would take 4 days. Fair enough. But suppose the same wizard wanted to craft [Spellstrike ammunition](http://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=167) - let's say arrows. Would it take 4 days to craft a single arrow? Or is there a rule somewhere stating that after 4 days, a quiver of, say 10, would be created?

Having it take just as long to craft a magical staff as it would take to craft a single magical arrow seems a little absurd to me - the first is a permanent item, the second is single-use.

Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## You can create 4 at a time.

Since [Spellstrike Ammunition](http://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=167) has the [consumable](http://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=36) trait, it can be crafted in batches, according to the Consumables and Ammunition section of [Crafting](https://2e.aonprd.com/Skills.aspx?ID=4):

> You can Craft items with the consumable trait in batches, making up to four of the same item at once with a single check. This requires you to include the raw materials for all the items in the batch at the start, and you must complete the batch all at once. You also Craft non-magical ammunition in batches, using the quantity listed in the Ranged Weapons table (typically 10).

If these were normal arrows, you could create ten at a time.